# Json Python Append List

Tags: python, json

I want to extract locality, postcode, and address from a json file. 
And append to a csv file with column names locality, postcode, and address.

Sample json file:

```
{

   "@graph": [

{
    "@id": "http://datos.madrid.es/egob/catalogo/tipo/entidadesyorganismos/6430067-bibliobus-numero-10-recorrido-semanal.json",
    "@type": "http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/entidadesYorganismos/Bibliobuses",
    "id": "6430067",
    "title": "Bibliobús número 10. Recorrido semanal",
    "relation": "http://www.madrid.es/sites/v/index.jsp?vgnextchannel=9e4c43db40317010VgnVCM100000dc0ca8c0RCRD&vgnextoid=734a6e6b06637310VgnVCM1000000b205a0aRCRD",
    "address": {
        "locality": "MADRID",           
        "postal-code": "",
        "street-address": "Servicio itinerante "
    },
    "organization": {
        "organization-desc": "",
        "accesibility": "0",
        "schedule": "Consulte en   documentación asociada   el detalle del Horario de verano",
        "services": "",
        "organization-name": "Bibliobús número 10. Recorrido semanal"
    }
},
{
    "@id": "http://datos.madrid.es/egob/catalogo/tipo/entidadesyorganismos/6431159-bibliobus-numero-11-recorrido-semanal.json",
    "@type": "http://datos.madrid.es/egob/kos/entidadesYorganismos/Bibliobuses",
    "id": "6431159",
    "title": "Bibliobús número 11. Recorrido semanal",
    "relation": "http://www.madrid.es/sites/v/index.jsp?vgnextchannel=9e4c43db40317010VgnVCM100000dc0ca8c0RCRD&vgnextoid=1d69b5f1cea37310VgnVCM1000000b205a0aRCRD",
    "address": {
        "locality": "MADRID",           
        "postal-code": "",
        "street-address": "Servicio itinerante "
    },
    "organization": {
        "organization-desc": "",
        "accesibility": "0",
        "schedule": "Consulte en   documentación asociada   el   detalle del horario de verano",
        "services": "",
        "organization-name": "Bibliobús número 11. Recorrido semanal"
    }     
  ]
}
```

## My Source Code

```
import json
import csv

sourcefile = open('bibliobuses.json', 'r', encoding='latin-1')
json_data = json.load(sourcefile)
print(json_data)

outputfile = open("convertedjson2.csv", "w", encoding="latin-1")
outputwriter = csv.writer(outputfile)

for station in json_data["@graph"]:
    header_row = []
    for attribute in station["address"]:
        header_row.append(attribute)
    outputwriter.writerow(header_row)

    listado = []

    for attribute in station["address"]:
        listado.append(station["address"]["locality"])
        listado.append(station["address"]["postal-code"])
        listado.append(station["address"]["street-address"])
    outputwriter.writerow(listado)
```

However, the outputwriter csv file shows the header rows repeated.

```
locality  postal-code street-adress
MADRID    NA          Servicio itinerante
locality  postal-code street-address
MADRID    NA          Servicio itinerante
locality  postal-code street-address
MADRID    NA          Servicio itinerante
locality  postal-code street-address
MADRID    NA          Servicio itinerante
locality  postal-code street-address
MADRID    NA          Servicio itinerante
locality  postal-code street-address
.
.
.
MADRID    28015       CALLE CONDE DUQUE 9
.
. 
.
```

How can I get one header row with their corresponding values?

Grateful for any help.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, you're explicitly appending to the header row for every row in the input. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am a beginner in python and parsing json documents. Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Everything you put inside the `for` loop happens for every item you iterate over. If you don't want something to happen over and over, it should be outside the loop. (That's not specific to Python or to JSON -- it's true of any programming language with looping constructs, which is to say in practical terms, *every* programming language with a higher level of abstraction than assembly).

Comment: @NathanSmith, if you're inclined to edit the question, it'd be more helpful to make the code a proper [mcve] (not requiring the user to download and create `.json` files first, for example). Reformatting the link without removing the need for it is avoiding the deeper problems.

Comment: @PabloUgarte. Move `header_row = []` to before the main loop. Then put the other three header loop lines inside an if-block with this statement: `if not header_row:`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the solution. Just did what you said but get repeated keys...

Comment: @PabloUgarte. No, the first three lines inside the main loop need to go inside the if-block. (PS: please don't change the code in your question).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you very much Very grateful!